# Redux Observables - Web socket over stomp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I'm very new to redux observables and I need to implement an epic to handle a web socket connection using Stomp.

Each time the payload is received from the connection I want to fire an action to update my store, the problem is the action doesn't ever seem to fire, can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
import { Observable, webSocket, Subject, ofType, mergeMap, map } from 'rxjs';
import { Stomp } from '@stomp/stompjs/lib/stomp';

import * as actions from 'actions/data/data';

const webSocketClient = Stomp.client('ws://some-url');

export function getData (action$) {
  return action$.ofType('REQUEST_DATA')
    .mergeMap(() =>
      webSocketClient.connect('test', 'test', () => {
        webSocketClient.subscribe('/test', payload => {
          actions.receiveData(payload);
        });
      })
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the source for `actions/data/data`?

Comment: Also: this code currently creates a connection to the socket every time `REQUEST_DATA` is received, but it never disconnects and since it uses `mergeMap` it's possible more than one `REQUEST_DATA` could come in concurrently. I noticed stomp doesn't protect you from this, in fact it leaks the WebSocket connection if you call connect more than once before disconnecting: https://github.com/jmesnil/stomp-websocket/blob/master/src/stomp.orig.js#L118 Is this an issue or nope?

Comment: thanks, @jayphelps, actions/data/data file can be found here - https://paste.laravel.io/679c11ea-d5d1-44c7-a2b8-aed9c200f5ed. For now we only want one request so I'd need some way or protecting against that. Is there any particular resource you recommend for getting better up to speed with this or should I just focus on both the Rxjs and redux-observables documentation?